# My matlab while loop isn't recognising my function button press

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I have a script that runs when a button is pressed causing a while loop to initiate. When my stop button is pressed it is supposed to cause the loop condition to be untrue thus stopping the loop. My stop button doesn't seem to stop the loop during testing. it would seem the value I assigned in the pushDisconnect button isn't updating to the while loop and i'm not sure why this is occurring.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushConnect.
function pushConnect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushConnect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.pushDisconnect,'Enable','on')
set(handles.pushConnect,'Enable','off')

handles.myDevice.StartAcquisition;
sampleRate_BP = double(handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.SamplesPerSecond);
axis_handles = zeros(1,handles.numEnabledBPChannels);
BioPotentialSignals = cell(1,handles.numEnabledBPChannels);
handles.CheckFinger = cell(1,5);
handles.stopNow = 0;

for ch = 1:handles.numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,'Parent',handles.uipanelGraph);
    if ch==1
        title(char(handles.deviceName))
    end
    ylabel([char(handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).Name) ' (V)']);
    hold on
end

xlabel('Time (s)')
linkaxes(axis_handles,'x')

plotWindow = 5;
plotGain_BP = 1;


while handles.stopNow == 0 
    for ch = 1:handles.numEnabledBPChannels
        BioPotentialSignals{ch} = [BioPotentialSignals{ch};handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).GetScaledValueArray.double'];
        if length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}) <= plotWindow*sampleRate_BP
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            t = (0:(length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-1))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch});
            xlim([0 plotWindow])
        else
            if ch==1
                t = ((length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-(plotWindow*sampleRate_BP-1)):length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            end
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch}(end-plotWindow*sampleRate_BP+1:end));
            xlim([t(end)-plotWindow t(end)])
        end
    end
    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    pause(0.1)
    disp(handles.stopNow)
end

% Stop signal
handles.myDevice.StopAcquisition;
% Disconnect from all sensors
handles.myDevice.Disconnect;

msgbox('Device requires cycling, in order to restablish connection. Closing program.')

% Close window
close all;

% --- Executes on button press in pushDisconnect.
function pushDisconnect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushDisconnect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.pushDisconnect,'Enable','off')

handles.stopNow = 1;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Final Working Code, if anyone is interested:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushConnect.
function pushConnect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushConnect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.pushDisconnect,'Enable','on')
set(handles.pushConnect,'Enable','off')

handles.myDevice.StartAcquisition;
sampleRate_BP = double(handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.SamplesPerSecond);
axis_handles = zeros(1,handles.numEnabledBPChannels);
BioPotentialSignals = cell(1,handles.numEnabledBPChannels);
handles.CheckFinger = cell(1,5);
handles.stopNow = 0;


for ch = 1:handles.numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,'Parent',handles.uipanelGraph);
    if ch==1
        title(char(handles.deviceName))
    end
    ylabel([char(handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).Name) ' (V)']);
    hold on
end

xlabel('Time (s)')
linkaxes(axis_handles,'x')

plotWindow = 5;
plotGain_BP = 1;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);


while handles.stopNow == 0
    for ch = 1:handles.numEnabledBPChannels
        BioPotentialSignals{ch} = [BioPotentialSignals{ch};handles.myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).GetScaledValueArray.double'];
        if length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}) <= plotWindow*sampleRate_BP
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            t = (0:(length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-1))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch});
            xlim([0 plotWindow])
        else
            if ch==1
                t = ((length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-(plotWindow*sampleRate_BP-1)):length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            end
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch}(end-plotWindow*sampleRate_BP+1:end));
            xlim([t(end)-plotWindow t(end)])
        end
    end
    handles = guidata(hObject);
    drawnow 
    pause(0.1)
end

% Stop signal
handles.myDevice.StopAcquisition;
% Disconnect from all sensors
handles.myDevice.Disconnect;

msgbox('Device requires cycling, in order to restablish connection. Closing program.')

% Close window
close all;


% --- Executes on button press in pushDisconnect.
function pushDisconnect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushDisconnect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.pushDisconnect,'Enable','off')

handles.stopNow = 1;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the `guidata(hObject, handles)` line, and replace it by `handles=guidata(hObject)` since you're overwriting the GUI state with whatever was current at the time the loop started, and you want to be polling the GUI state instead. Put the `guidata(hObject, handles)`-line before the loop, to ensure that `handles.stopNow` is indeed reset to 0.

If that doesn't help, an additional problem may be that Matlab waits with processing commands from one button callback until the other callback is done running.

Two things you can try: Add a `drawnow` command before the pause. This will force the GUI to update, and processes all the interactions. Also, make sure that the pushbutton callback for `pushConnect` is interruptible.

Comment: Tried both, still the same problem.

Comment: @IamTrent: just noticed the guidata line. You're overwriting the GUI state, ensuring that handles.stopNow never becomes one! Answer has been edited.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: @IamTrent: just noticed another issue :)

Comment: I get this error when I try the latest method: 'Reference to non-existent field 'stopNow'.'

Comment: Got it working now, I needed the 'guidata(hObject, handles);' before the while loop as well as your polling handles. Thank you so much for your help, do you happen to know where I can read up more on 'handles=guidata(hObject)' still trying to work out when it's appropriate to use these parts of guidata. Thank you again!

Comment: (1) set the field `stopNow` in your `openingFcn`. It's bad practice to create fields inside a callback. (2) Before your while-loop, add `guidata(hObject,handles)` to ensure `stopNow` is set to 0.

Comment: @IamTrent: `handles` is where the GUI state is stored. `handles=guidata(hObject,handles)` reads the state, `guidata(hObject,handles)` writes the state. Unlike handle objects, `handles` is not pass-by-reference, so you need to update manually.

Comment: @IamTrent: No problem, Matlab GUIs can be a bit obscure at times :)